# Color Options Missing in Strategy in Pine Script V4

Tags: pine-script

[With Color Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8c6K.jpg)
[Without/Missing Color Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ujh4q.jpg)

I have an Indicator (Version 2) converted to Strategy (Version 4). After converting, it seems odd that color options is nowhere to be found. Not sure if because of too much plots being made or something that I missed. The indicator of Version 2 is fine showing the color options, but after I manually converted it I got this issue. To change color need to manually adjust the script.

Sample code:
plot(b, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_line, title="Title", color=color.new(color=color.navy, transp=50))

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire code that you have so far.

Comment: Found out if I use the old method plot(b, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_line, title="Title", color=color.navy, transp=50) it works fine but will give feedback that it will be deprecated soon.

Answer (score 0):

Colors are not handled the same way in v2 and v4 of Pine. The introduction of `color.rgb()` in v4 and the fact that "series color" can now be used in more places have had impacts on the behavior of the "Style" tab. See the [Pine usrman on the subject](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Colors.html#color-selection-through-script-settings) for more info.